# Any possibility to display Map<String, String> in a apache wicket table (DataView), without getting key list

Tags: java, wicket, dataview

I create a table in html page.

There are two columns in that table.

1. `wicket:id = “key_column”`
2. `wicket:id = “value_column”`

I'm going to display map data (key and value).

How I solved this is ..

```
TreeMap<String, String> map = new Treemap<~>();
map = getDataFormProvider();

List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<~>();

for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    keyList.add(key);
}

DataView<String> dataView = new DataView<~>("displayPanel", new ListDataProvider(keyList)) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(Item item) {
        String key = (String) item.getModelObject();
        item.add(new Label("key_column", key));
        item.add(new Label("value_column", map.get(key)));
    }
};
```

Is there any possibility to display `map` as a table directly without getting `keyList` like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. But you can reduce the code passing the list of entries:

```
DataView<Entry<String, String>> dataView = new DataView<~>("displayPanel", new ListDataProvider(new ArrayList<Entry<String, String>(map.entrySet())) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(Item item) {
        Entry<String, String> entry = item.getModelObject();
        item.add(new Label("key_column", entry.getKey()));
        item.add(new Label("value_column", entry.getValue()));
    }
});
```

Comment: Can not find .toList() option.

Comment: Sorry @darshakat it's without the '.toList()'. At first, I thought a Set had the toList method, then I checked but I forgot to removed it.